# Can I ask this question on 1 Timothy 2:12-15

Tags: discussion

What is Paul trying to say here?

> I do not permit a woman to teach or to exercise authority over a man; rather, she is to remain quiet. For Adam was formed first, then Eve; and Adam was not deceived, but the woman was deceived and became a transgressor. Yet she will be saved through childbearing—if they continue in faith and love and holiness, with self-control.
>   (1 Timothy 2:12-15 ESV)

---

^ That's the question I'm wondering about.

There's a lot of ambiguity right now about what's allowed and what's not, which is why I'm posting this here first.

My intent with this question is this:

I would like to get interpretations of this verse from others who have studied it, from any doctrinal perspective.

---

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

OK... Well, if you're looking for *doctrine* on the topic (four our purposes here, *application* of the passage), you really need to be on Christianity.SE.

If you're attempting to understand the meaning that the author (Paul) is trying to convey, this may or may not be the place.  [Watch this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/122/women-speaking-in-church-in-1-cor-1434-35) and see what happens along with [this meta post](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-much-doctrine-should-we-allow-what-is-the-general-guideline) until we can get some good guidelines.

I personally think that all interpretation is acceptable *up to the point of application*.  Meaning, I think it's alright to ask "What does this mean?", but not alright to ask "Should we abide by this?" or "How can we apply this today?"

(But again, I'd watch [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/122/women-speaking-in-church-in-1-cor-1434-35) to see what happens.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Richard. I'll watch the question, and have commented both on the question itself and the meta post.