# Could we revise the help center explanation of what’s on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have a section in our help center called [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and another called [What types kinds of questions should I avoid asking?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) The latter contains generic SE guidelines that seem to be appropriate. The former is our chance to explain site scope, and I think it could be improved.

One thing I’ve noticed in our recent discussions of off-topic reasons is that we have a remarkable degree of **agreement about the appropriate boundaries for this site**. We just like different numbers of words, want to organize sentences differently, prefer to use a thesaurus more or less, etc. etc.

Regardless of what we do for close reasons, each must adhere to the 400 character limit. I wonder if the help section might be an opportunity to provide some slightly expanded yet organized (in a way that Meta could never be) education about *what we agree about* for newcomers.

Here it is as it stands:

> ***If your question is about...***
>
> interpretation of a specific Bible passage
>
> hermeneutical approaches
>
> translation of Biblical texts
>
> historical context (with regards to a particular text)
>
> source criticism
>
> ***... then this is the right place to ask.***
>
> Questions that **do not [arise from](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/a-new-guideline-for-doctrine-in-questions-what-do-you-think) a Biblical text** are **off-topic** unless they are about hermeneutical approaches.
>
> ---
>
> Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.
>
> For more help, see ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that there are two main audiences for this page:

1. People who meander onto Hermeneutics.SE and want to learn what we’re about before asking questions. (Rare!)
2. People who have been rebuked for asking off-topic questions and are trying to do better.

Within both groups there are probably those who just want a few bullets and others who really want to *understand*. Meta is available, but one could spend *days* trying to sort this out by reading Meta posts. Our current ‘on-topic’page is nice in that it has bullets that are short and simple. Unfortunately, topicality on Hermeneutics.SE is actually not simple....

My proposal is to leave a simple, bulleted version (with revisions as suggested below) at the top and then provide a more extended explanation below for those who are interested. For the latter, I wonder if some adaptation of ScottS’s [“Original Long Form” of proposed close reasons](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3180/3555) would be appropriate. I defer to him for that and turn now to the bullets.

My concerns about the bullets as they stand:

- The terminology of the first bullet “a specific Bible passage” is abundantly clear. We then use three other terms: Biblical texts, a particular text, a Biblical text. I don’t think the “text” terminology is helpful to the average visitor. If we mean “a particular passage,” we should just say that. If we mean “the Bible,” we should say that. I don’t think people consistently understand anything more subtle.
- The third bullet, to me, indicates that general questions about translation philosophy (*not* about a specific passage) *are* on topic, but I don’t see how that jives with the statement at the bottom.
- [Most people don’t know what source criticism is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDRH9.png) (That was ~5 months into my foray here, and although I’m not as savvy as many here, I’m also probably not *less* savvy than the average visitor.)
- We need to include text criticism, and most people don’t know what *that* is either.
- If the statement at the bottom is meant to indicate “a specific passage,” then there are more exceptions (authorship, source criticism, text criticism, dating...).

My proposal:

> Questions are *on-topic* if they **arise from a specific Bible passage or group of closely related passages** and are seeking to understand:
>
> - the author’s intended meaning;
> - translation between the original language, ancient versions, and English;
> - historical context;
> - variations in the wording between manuscripts;
> - authorship, dating, and sources used.
>
> Questions are also *on-topic* if they are about:
>
> - hermeneutical approaches to interpretation of the Bible;
> - techniques used by scholars to determine the original wording of the Bible.

Comment: I'd be loath to see the "arise from a Biblical text" wording go. Perhaps "Questions are on-topic if they arise from a specific Bible passage or group of closely related passages and are seeking to understand:" would be a way of keeping it?

Comment: I have no problem with that; hadn't even noticed, but you're right that it's nice wording. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I like this a lot!

Comment: I like this bullet points using simple language, though _perhaps_ we ought to also "educate" just a bit, including after the simple language statements the more technical terms relevant (i.e. text criticism, source criticism, etc.).

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of "group of closely related passages". Related on what basis? I can see the garden-variety proof-texter understanding this as 'they all have the same topic theologically' or 'they have the same English word in them' or 'my cross-reference tool links them'. The connections here need more basis than that, and I think we need to capture that somehow.

Comment: At the same time, I can think of no better way to word that without getting ridiculously complicated.

Comment: @Dan I’m not opposed to asterisk + footnote with explanation. The alternative we’re starting with is “a Biblical text”, and I don’t know what *that* means either.

Comment: Even better would probably be linking that phrase to a meta post explaining it further

Comment: Multiple passage questions are comparatively rare, so perhaps that can just be left out.

Answer (score 3):

Add below the bullet points of [Susan's great answer](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3186/2070) more explanation for those wanting it and links to particularly relevant meta posts (anyone feel free to edit this and add relevant points and/or links—or create your own answer to add similar bullet points to what might be included in this help center update).

> To explain further, we are about
>
> - **Techniques or rules of interpretation** which are known as a [hermeneutic](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12854/what-is-hermeneutics), and relate to [exegesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/36/what-is-the-difference-between-exegesis-and-hermeneutics).
> - **Textual history of the Bible**, whether extant (existing) documents themselves or theoretical historical forms of the [Biblical texts](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-texts-are-open-for-examination).
> - **Interpretation of Biblical texts** based upon one's hermeneutic, but [demonstrated by showing one's work of how the hermeneutic arrives at their interpretation](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-are-we-looking-for-in-answers/533#533), not merely stating their opinion.
> - **Hebrew, Aramaic, and Greek language** in the context of interpreting a particular passage. Note: Unfortunately, language mechanics of these or other languages the texts have been translated into are outside the scope of this site, and we encourage you to support the [Greek language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74469/greek-language) or [Hebrew language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language) site proposals, or direct the question to the [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) site, or an appropriate [modern language site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation).

Comment: I concur. I believe in leaving the simple explanations intact, but adding 'bullet points' to further add to their explanations. The average 1st time user will get as far as the basic explanation-terse, and to the point. The Main Point of Concern is for those who screen the 1st time posts, and other editing criteria. There has been a 'confluence of confusion' regarding our Site Directives, and the bullet points help to clarify areas in which editing is required.

Comment: Greek language site proposal no longer exists