# How is my question about a hermeneutical approach off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I would like to understand why [my question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33730/are-there-extant-any-examples-of-accounts-being-deliberately-out-of-chronologica) about chronology was considered off-topic.

The close reason given is:

> "Questions including a biblical text but that are not seeking an
>   answer about ① the history of that biblical text itself or ② the
>   meaning of that biblical text either in context or through a process
>   of arriving at a particular interpretation of it are off-topic."

However, it seems clear that questions about specific hermeneutical approaches are on-topic even if they are not asking about a specific text. As stated in the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question is about...
>
> interpretation of a specific Bible passage
>
> **hermeneutical approaches**
>
> translation of Biblical texts
>
> historical context (with regards to a particular text)
>
> source criticism
>
> ... then this is the right place to ask. (My emphasis)

And:

> Questions that do not arise from a Biblical text are off-topic **unless
>   they are about hermeneutical approaches**. (My emphasis)

See also [these](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/questions-about-the-field-of-textual-criticism-without-reference-to-a-particular) [two](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/could-we-revise-the-help-center-explanation-of-what-s-on-topic) Meta posts.

As my question was about a hermeneutical approach, I am wondering why it was deemed off-topic.

Is it because the users disagree that the principle being discussed qualifies as a "hermeneutical approach"?

Is it because the title makes it seem that the question is simply asking for examples of a phenomenon (which was not the intent of the question – the title was edited by someone else)?

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer for those that voted to close it, since I was not one. Some things I see that probably need correcting:

1. I agree with you, the question retitling [was poorly done by Ruminator](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/33730/revisions), as the new title definitely implies you are seeking other examples of such out-of-order chronology in Scripture (which would *not* be on topic, as it seeks texts), when what you state you are seeking is other interpretive approaches recognizing such a phenomenon. So I suggest you revise the title, but it is best to try to make it a question. Maybe something like "Are there non-Rabbinical hermeneutics that recognize deliberate, non-chronological ordering of texts in the Pentateuch?"
2. You might consider editing your primary question (besides putting question mark on it, which should occur):

   > My question here is whether there are any other streams of thought (besides rabbinic interpretation) that subscribe to this principle.

   I would suggest either changing or adding wording at the end, where you state "that subscribe to this principle." Maybe similar to what I used in the paragraph above: "that recognize such a phenomenon" or "that subscribe to this principle or recognize such a phenomenon."

From my perspective, that is a valid question, but my reason for the change proposed in #2 is that my hermeneutics (grammatical/historical) from my theological perspective (divinely inspired text, chiefly Mosaic authorship of the Pentateuch) *recognizes* certain such cases, but I would not qualify it as a "principle" that is subscribed to.

At any rate, even fixing #1 would cause me to vote to reopen.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.