# Can we define as a forum what it means to "apply the text"? Where do we draw the line?

Tags: discussion

This is in response to [an attempt I made at an edit](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/luke-1619-31-what-indications-do-we-have-contextually-to-determine-if-the-acco) and [discussion that ensued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13495252#13495252), which in turn lead to [a Meta question](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/897/why-cant-we-ask-whether-hades-is-literal-or-figurative).  We know that this site focuses on meaning of the text, and stops short of application.  It appears there is [a generally accepted understanding that we will seek to avoid questions that pertain to applying the text and that the bottom line is whether intent of the questioner to understand the text.](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/a-new-guideline-for-doctrine-in-questions-what-do-you-think).  That seems notably subjective.  Can we agree upon some guidelines as to what constitutes applying the text?

Comment: Those are clear and helpful.  Dan has been endeavoring to demonstrate that the question I suggest--"What textual/contextual indications of do we have to determine if Hades in, Luke 16:19-31, is literal or figurative?"--is off topic. I am just not seeing it.  I am wondering if I am missing something, or if Dan's perspective does not reflect that of the forum.

Answer (score 4):

I've been giving this a little thought, and it is a difficult question. But some word-pairs started forming, and they seemed to provide a helpful diagnostic. I'm not sure how helpful this will be but ... FWIW, then (**n.b.** ALL of these assume textually-based questions -- that's a given):

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|       On-topic        |       Off-topic       |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| - what the text meant | - what the text means |
| - text production     | - text consumption    |
| - descriptive         | - prescriptive        |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

**(1) Meant/Means**: This is, of course [Krister Stendahl](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3260310)'s (in)famous distinction that has been [much discussed and criticized](http://www.directionjournal.org/26/2/flowering-and-floundering-of-old.html), and each of my three word-pairs relates to it. Essentially, though, as a diagnostic tool, if any given Q&A is attending to the linguistic, literary, or theological dimensions of the text as it was understood by its authors and reading community in antiquity (what it "meant", past tense), we'll be on safe ground.

**(2) Production/Consumption**: This might simply be another way of saying (1), but this shifts the perspective from "meaning" (as in (1)), to the activity around or processes in the text. If the Q&A is orientated towards processes and actions of textual "production" (authorship, editing, transmission), rather than "consumption", i.e., the text's use and adoption by recent or contemporary reading communities, then we'll be on safe ground.<sup>1</sup>

**(3) Descriptive/Prescriptive**: This is sometime stated in terms of "descriptive" *versus* "normative", especially in Brevard Childs's well-known [essay on theological commentary](http://int.sagepub.com/content/18/4/432.extract). If something is being *prescribed* for readers of BH.SE, or if the Q&A in some measure is implying *norms* binding on readers here ... [that's a problem](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/892/2215). On the other hand, if a Q&A is *describing* the linguistic, literary, or theological dimensions of the text as it was understood by its authors and reading community in antiquity, then we'll be on safe ground.

Would these diagnostic word-pairs have helped in the cases of contentious questions in the past? I'm not sure, but these might be helpful tools for the discussions that ensue.

Any other word-pairs that could flesh this out? Or has this already been hashed through in some other meta-post that I haven't yet found?

---

*Notes*

1. Of course, we might be interested in "consumption" by reading communities in antiquity -- that's part of (1), after all.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on [this post](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/415/43) from a while back. The logic there is the kind of reasoning that convinces me that the distinctions you are drawing here are largely artificial.

Comment: @JackDouglas : read the post you linked slowly and carefully; needs more than 600 characters to reply! In brief, note my (1) above includes "theological"; it *is* inherent in the text. My attempt here, which you're finding "artificial", is to root BH.SE discussions in the world of the text and its earliest readers in a descriptive mode. What I'm resisting (here! there are other places where it is *right*) is making *normative* or *prescriptive* claims arising from contemporary faith communities. My sense is that it's not a difficult (or artificial :) distinction to draw. ... /2 (cont'd)

Comment: ... (cont'd) Take, for example, an [answer instanced in the post you linked](http://goo.gl/J0RBYL). My judgement here is that it is simply bad Christian theology, and actually adds nothing to understanding Ecclesiastes (note the context in Eccl 4!). The further trinitarian reflections incline towards the Christian heresy of tri-theism, actually. And my typical experience in bumping into such here (on the Christian side) is that the grasp on Christian doctrine itself is so shallow that not only do we "theology", we're getting "**bad** theology"! Can dig out examples, but need to run just now.

Comment: I really want to emphasize that I appreciate your input here on meta as much as I do on the main site (which is a lot). This is the perfect place to hash things out and of course no two of us will always agree on everything! In that context I hope you'll take what I say in the right spirit :) On the subject of 'good' vs 'bad' theology, the problem (as I see it) is that it requires an objective human judge on the site to distinguish between the two, and we don't have one. It's fine to judge by the non-religious standards of clarity, comprehensibility or just community approval measured by...

Comment: ...votes, but I've come to think that it isn't helpful to call [one theology 'good' and another 'bad'](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/828/43). Of course we all think we are right, but I try hard to vote according to how clear the logic is in a post: whether I can understand your steps, and not whether I agree with your framework. If a post is clear I often find there are ideas that I can assimilate even if I fundamentally disagree with the conclusions: in other words, I don't have to agree with what you are writing to find your posts *useful*. (In your particular case I think...

Comment: ... both are true but that doesn't actually matter!). I should explain what I meant by 'artificial'. What I meant is that the line you draw is essentially a theological line that favours particular methods of interpreting the text. The posts you indicate are not 'prescriptive' are in fact perscriptive, just in a different domain: for example a statement about how a Greek work should be translated is 'application' to us reading the text today. It indicates how we should understand the word in 2014. I'd go further and say that 'application' in that broad sense is the only point of this or any...

Comment: ... site, because if what we read has no utility in 2014 then there is no point reading it at all! In which case why specifically disbar other kinds of application, for example the moral kind? A simple answer is that these are complex issues that involves more complex reasoning then can fit in an answer, but if that is the case, then they are already out of bounds by virtue of our insistence that we must 'show our work'. I've already argued in my answer here that the whole idea of defining site scope in religious/moral terms is not the best idea so I won't rehash that here :)

Comment: @JackDouglas Thanks for this! Three (I think) quick replies. (1) "Right spirit": affirmed and understood. :) (2) "Good v. bad theology": this isn't a personal judgment call. My definition of "bad theology" is that which is excluded by the historic [seven ecumenical church councils](http://goo.gl/yaNgJi) and excluded as heretical by Catholic, Orthodox, and Protestant churches. Not so subjective. :) There are standards. (3) "Artificial = essentially theological": no, the line is essentially historical. This is the [discourse problem](http://goo.gl/HVU7HX): religious orthopraxy != history! :)

Comment: The problem with (2) is that this site has nothing (directly) to do with Catholic, Orthodox, or Protestant churches: [We welcome Jewish, Christian, Atheist and other viewpoints as long as they take seriously the process of understanding the Biblical texts](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In practice the site has a Christian (and to a lesser extent a Jewish) flavour, which is not a bad thing, but we aren't essentially here to promote one means of reading the text over another, as long as the text is respected (which is itself a subjective judgement deserving its own post)

Comment: More personally speaking, I'd still call your definition of bad theology subjective: [Let God be true though every one were a liar](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans+3%3A4&version=ESV)! I don't even know what those ecumenical councils produced, much less the religious context of their times, but I'm passionately interested in the text and always seeking to understand it on it's own terms. You might think me a fool to dismiss the prior work of every man, but I am suspicious of hermeneutics that rely on tradition and who is to judge between us? :)

Comment: (well I had to read up on the Nicine creed to [write this answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity/24241#24241), but I stand by my broad profession of ignorance of church history :)

Comment: @Davïd I think this post is brilliant, and this is exactly the direction I believe this site should be going in. You may have noticed that not all of us agree here, and that's OK! We are all free to express our opinions on meta. But FYI, I fully agree with this post and believe this is where the site needs to be heading.

Comment: You may be interested in reading [this meta post](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/672/423) where I make the case that using first person plural language in reference to the audience of a text applies it (in the way we don't want here, at least in my view) and also imposes the OP's beliefs upon the reader.

Comment: @JackDouglas Perhaps I've misunderstood you. In your [earlier post](http://goo.gl/GRwnTY) you wrote: "I disagree with those who think his answer is diminished in quality because he reads the passage through a Christian lens". So you seem are welcoming "Christian doctrine" in BH.SE answers (which I take it is the drift of that earlier post). I intended in my comments here "about good/bad theology" to appeal to criteria applicable to the *entire* Christian spectrum, which seems right IF you're welcoming Christian doctrine in BH.SE answers. ... /2 (cont'd)

Comment: ... (cont'd) But then you go on, above: "The problem with (2) is that this site has nothing (directly) to do with Catholic, Orthodox, or Protestant churches". Which was my point in this post to begin with! I see an inconsistency here, and I don't think you can have it both ways. Either you welcome "doctrine", and relevant standards apply to it; or you banish "doctrine" (as this post attempts to make a case for) and have done with it. Trying to do *both* isn't to sit on the fence ... it's to sit on a razor blade! (Ouch!)

Comment: @Daи - re: 1st person plurals : yes, a very helpful diagnostic. I've seen it in academic writing, too, and it's usually a tell-tale sign of imposing a group mentality, often when least warranted. (Sometimes used "rhetorically", but that's not what we're [ahem!] talking about at the moment.)

Comment: OK, I have misunderstood you (though I wasn't the author of that earlier post I linked, that's Soldarnal, the no. 2 user on the site by all-time rep). You are seeking to apply that standard to those who's answers are identifiably Christian and not to Jews, atheist and others then? I am consistently opposed to any attempt to define what is allowed here in any religious terms, including the use of the word "doctrine" at all! I don't welcome "doctrine" because we can't even agree what the word means. To me, banishing doctrine would [be an oxymoron](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/7497/43)

Comment: I'm all for relevant standards (eg: 1. respect the text, 2. start from the text, 3. show your work upwards from the text), but I want the standards to be focused on the texts that are our subject, and not on the religions that hold them to be true.

Comment: @Gone that is in the context of judging what is 'offensive' not judging what is an allowed in terms of answer scope.

Comment: @JackDouglas So it looks like I was a tad muddled then - apologies! I'm not sure I've gained clarity yet, but then ... BH.SE has been [852 days in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics), so I shouldn't expect to suss it in a month! ;)

Comment: Davïd @GoneQuiet is quite right, you shouldn't assume I'm right, I've been wrong plenty of times before here. I'm just trying to be as wise as I can with the experience I have got, and I'm especially concerned with keeping us 'useful' to our real audience, and with minimizing (not eliminating of course) the natural tendency towards conflict when folk with strongly held beliefs come into contact with each other here, and surprisingly or unsurprisingly I'm not quite sure, that often stems from misunderstanding or assumptions about definitions of words!

Comment: @All Boy, I guess I missed it! I thought this was a 'settled' issue, that questions which start from the text and can be answered by the text are "on topic". "Assuming neutrality" is a non-starter, it might suffice when explaining Heisenberg's Principle, but not when we actually believe what we are talking about. God is NOT neutral, neither are those who believe in Him. We come together to discuss the Scriptures, therefore, let the text be our framework for discussion.

Comment: I think this post could come in handy for our current discussion of close reasons.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we define as a forum what it means to “apply the text”?

This is an interesting question and  I'm going to suggest the answer is "No".

I'll explain my reasoning but first I'll list in general terms what I think we *do have clearly defined* and explain why I think what we have is superior to the alternative. I'm limiting my scope here to textual/exegetical questions/answers that are the source of most debate (rather than historical questions or those about specific hermeneutics):

1. Respect the text
2. Start from the text
3. Work upwards from the text joining the dots

The interesting thing to note about these guidelines is that the words used are relatively easy to understand and agree on. There are indeed [debates about what "the text" is](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/43) but it's incredibly rare for that esoteric debate to make any practical difference to the site. Dan made a heroic attempt to 
exhaustively list and categorize the exact texts, but in practice we pretty much all knew what texts were on-topic. There are occasionally difficulties in deciding whether a question *really* starts from a text, or merely quotes a convenient text in lip-service to the guidelines and focuses on an 'idea' instead: I think we've been pretty successful in shutting these down. In short ***these guidelines are broadly understood, even by newcomers***

At the other end of the spectrum we have words like 'doctrine', 'truth', 'Truth' and 'neutral', the understanding of which is heavily influenced by the framework you start from: even high-rep and highly respected regulars on the site [commonly disagree](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/897/why-cant-we-ask-whether-hades-is-literal-or-figurative/899#comment2778_897) on the definitions of these words. ***If we can't agree on them, how can we hope to usefully define the scope of the site using them?***.

Back to the question, I think that the word "application" broadly fits into the latter category ([as evidenced here for example](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-are-we-looking-for-in-answers#comment1368_533)). It's not that useful for defining site scope because we all use it to mean something subtly different, *it is a religiously loaded word*, and this is the nub of my point, ***it is better to define site guidelines without using religiously loaded words***, not least because our raison d'être is *the text*, and [not religion](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> We welcome Jewish, Christian, Atheist and other viewpoints as long as they take seriously the process of understanding the Biblical texts. The answers we rate most highly stem from and work up from the text.

Finally, we don't *need* to use or 'define' the word 'application', because ***the (good part of the) aim of doing so is already achieved*** using better understood words and in a more flexible way. It's generally impossible to start from the text showing your work all the way up to your conclusions and also have your answer loaded with 'application' (understood as the last stage of the interpretive process), simply because that is usually a very long way away from the text.

Comment: "Respect the text" is not so "relatively easy to understand and agree on." For me, if on does not consider it God's word, then it is disrespected (so many do not start there). [You realize issues with that wording](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/898/can-we-define-as-a-forum-what-it-means-to-apply-the-text-where-do-we-draw-the/900#comment2844_903). I think the descriptive/prescriptive of @Davïd is the "best" formulation. Some texts are naturally "commands," and also the whole text we are commanded to "believe," so it is by nature a "prescriptive" set of documents. ...

Comment: ... but I agree that a big point is as @Daи notes regarding the [first person plural](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/898/can-we-define-as-a-forum-what-it-means-to-apply-the-text-where-do-we-draw-the/900#comment2851_903), and really any 2nd person reference to the reader is language of "you" or "we" need to.... A less prescriptive "tone" is through using third person, or generic terms "believers," "people," etc. I believe Truth (hehehe :-) ) will find application by the Spirit simply by its statement/explanation, without necessarily turning it into a command.

Comment: So in short, I generally agree with your position, though I think "application" is almost immediate upon having an interpretation, and is not really "a very long way away from the text" at all.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, btw when I said "respect the text" is "relatively easy to understand and agree on" I did not mean we would all agree what the definition should be, just that the definition we have here (which is something like a loose concept of 'caring' about the text rather than 'sneering' at it) isn't ambiguous and it is easy to agree what the definition means (not what it 'should' be). Does that makes sense?